# OpenDirect deep link not working for push notifications

Tags: mobilepush, push-notification

We are managing push notifications for both Android and iOS via Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK for React Native.

We have set up deep linking within the app and tested it. The app opens a deep link correctly if you just type it in the browser. Example:

```
 app://campaign/{campaignId} in the browser would redirect to a correct campaign within our native app.
```

When we enable OpenDirect for push notifications within SMC and send the exact same url then after you click a notification on a physical device it only opens the default page of native app (rather than a specific campaign in this case).

Is there something im missing in the setup?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not an answer, but you should note that app-specific URI schemes are effectively deprecated in favour of Universal Links. [This article](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/universal-links-for-android-and-ios-1ddb1e70cab0) explains the difference from deep links and the advantages of universal links quite well (and goes into lots of other details too).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Since we only want to use these links in our push notifications i think it makes sense to only go for deep links rather than universal links (its not possible to receive a push notification and not have the app installed, so the deep link should always work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that push notifications are not designed to be "links". Each push notification can carry its own data. You have to listen for them in the code and react to their payload accordingly (for example by rerouting the user if the push notification carries a deep link).

Case closed.